# Find a document in a loop

Tags: mongodb

I am relatively new to mongodb, so please be patient. Suppose I have the following documents in my collection:

```
{_id:"3",name:'three',parentId:"2.1"}, 
{_id:"2.1",name:'two1',parentId:"1"},
{_id:"2.2",name:'two2',parentId:"1"}, 
{_id:"1",name:'one'}
```

I have a `db.mycoll.find({name:"three"})` which returns me the document with _id 3. I need based on this find document with _id 1.

Basically this represents something like a folder structure. So the top level is 'one', which has 'two1' and 'two2'. The 'two1' in turn has 'three'. Having the id of 'three' I need to get it's top level parent. Is there a way to do it in mongo or do I have to return results to the client, process them there and call mongo for each iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked for me:

```
  ...find().forEach(
        function getParent(itemId) {
            var sub = db.mycoll.findOne({_id: itemId});
            if(sub) {
                if(sub.parentId) {
                    getParent(sub.parentId)
                } 
                else /*top level*/
                    print(sub.name)
            }
        }
    )
```

Hope it helps someone else